# Cognos-11 Date Prompts - How do I add in an filter for 'previous 8 weeks'?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I am very new to the coding side of Cognos!

I am trying to set up an auto-report that will run every Monday but calculate the previous 8 weeks worth of data. I have added the prompt button to show 'Last 8 weeks', but now I am not sure how to add it as an actual filter. These are my current date filters:

````
case 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'EnteredDates'
then    case
        when ?p_StartDate? <> current_date
        then ?p_StartDate?
        else _add_days (current_date, -1) 
        end
when ?p_DateCat? = 'Yesterday'
then _add_days (current_date, -1) 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'ThisWeek'
then _add_days (current_date, 1-(_day_of_week (current_date, 1))) 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'ThisMonth'
then _add_days (current_date, 1-(_day (current_date))) 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'LastMonth'
then _add_months (_first_of_month (current_date), -1)
end

and

case 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'EnteredDates'
then    case
        when ?p_EndDate? <> current_date
        then ?p_EndDate?
        else _add_days (current_date, -1) 
        end
when ?p_DateCat? = 'Yesterday'
then _add_days (current_date, -1) 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'ThisWeek'
then _add_days (current_date, -1) 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'ThisMonth'
then _add_days (current_date, -1) 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'LastMonth'
then _last_of_month(_add_months (current_date, -1))
end```
````

Comment: I have tried something like this: 
when ?p_DateCat? = 'Last 8 Weeks'
then _add_days( current_date(), -56)

But I just get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
[DateField]   >=  _add_days (current_date, -56)

or

[DateField]  between _add_days (current_date, -56)  and _add_days (current_date, -1)

Syntax error was because of the other lines. Once removed it ran perfectly for the requested 56 day period!